# ggplot Axis scaling

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes

Following script is used to plot data on one common x and two distinctly scaled y-axes:

```
scale <- max(data$one) / max(data$two)
#See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right

ggplot(data3, aes(x=time)) +
  labs(title = "Title", x="Time") +
  geom_line(aes(x=time, y=one, col="cf_media")) +
  geom_line(aes(x=time, y=two * scale, col="two")) + 
  scale_x_date(breaks=scales::pretty_breaks(n = 6), expand = c(0,0)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Left Axis",
                     sec.axis=sec_axis(~./scale, 
                                       breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 6),
                                       name="Right Axis"),
                     minor_breaks=NULL,
                     breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 6)) +
  theme(legend.position = c(.90, .95),
        legend.title=element_blank())
```

**Out:**

[image]

The problem with this graph is, that, for some reason, the left axis (red line) doesn't scale appropriately. The minimum axis value is way below the true min. Among 20 graphs, this is the only one that seems to have this error. The right axis (blue) seems just fine.

**Question: What's the best way to plot these two time series appropriately with two distinct y-axes, possibly without adding `limits=`?**

The data is pasted below.

Thanks for your help!

**dput(data):**

```
structure(list(time = structure(c(15431, 15461, 15492, 15522, 
15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 15706, 15737, 15765, 15796, 
15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 15979, 16010, 16040, 16071, 
16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 16344, 
16375, 16405, 16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 16556, 16587, 16617, 
16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770, 16801, 16832, 16861), class = "Date"), 
    one = c(18.4221796200761, 18.3967231898903, 16.335633117503, 
    16.730296027773, 18.1514409360143, 17.7199441162588, 16.799170250284, 
    15.4179238554614, 17.4392839966129, 17.595792430154, 16.9553497988467, 
    16.4953670246957, 17.5849417055811, 17.9678266256, 17.1739918955819, 
    17.6002431353711, 17.9595179193721, 17.999935039935, 17.7524652108263, 
    17.7177489902007, 17.3588650113878, 17.6725182139017, 17.4405657957642, 
    17.6704974950091, 17.8875447511326, 16.9658703405016, 17.4780706514254, 
    18.1277851044477, 18.1761216072241, 17.1620759199987, 18.4686443856938, 
    18.5762732410043, 17.4880377648686, 17.829055609543, 18.3096877847122, 
    16.9076887297865, 17.8248723024602, 17.9126225373526, 17.6292589941241, 
    18.5179618982914, 18.5366398684046, 18.0677764393526, 16.6418177564593, 
    16.9211415340111, 17.9654709207359, 17.6361844282822, 18.2270338206168, 
    16.4429651207772), two = c(16.6582662387643, 16.6291067627203, 
    16.6371145606996, 16.4961540261816, 17.0596826781454, 16.7062765725755, 
    16.7162150801773, 16.5497433654548, 16.289748798776, 16.2175637229181, 
    16.2087465723472, 16.7917693011438, 17.0844034991311, 17.1252018488917, 
    17.035226133743, 16.7162471713475, 16.7691021105687, 16.2972221957997, 
    16.708788985733, 16.7827078467867, 16.4754347061264, 16.0403929689546, 
    16.2594260331233, 16.6004611360169, 16.6892567341726, 16.7962173532738, 
    16.4205670536356, 16.9984920528234, 16.3600444060327, 16.2367171945242, 
    16.5735658839198, 16.5205739998051, 16.483858284178, 15.7240973247951, 
    17.0266878151606, 16.9142806023417, 16.788529867979, 16.5935730790947, 
    16.424863694705, 17.0269967594955, 16.3278055932357, 16.3832866771369, 
    16.6118799527132, 16.8515435281064, 16.8155186621117, 15.5626066989097, 
    16.2053235276769, 16.9638862520006)), .Names = c("time", 
"one", "two"), row.names = c(NA, 48L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work with the data you provided.

Comment: Can you try now?

Comment: Excuse, I adjusted it.

Comment: I like to scale the left axis so that i used more of the horizontal space. That way, it can be better compared.

Comment: Is your plot generated by your example data? I ran your code (after correcting the name of the data source), but the left & right axis labels are the other way round.

Comment: Can you explain? Left axis should be red, right axis should be blue. I also wasn't sure whether the `scale <-`approach is the best, but apparently I did not find anything better.

Comment: Please, double check the chart in your question. It doesn't match to the given data and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to scale the second time series `two` so that the scaled values lie within the same interval as the values of time series `one`.

To achieve this, we need to scale the *range* as well as to consider an offset, i.e.,

*one* = *scl* * *two* + *ofs*

The values of `scl` and `ofs` can be determined from the `min()` and `max()` values of `one` and `two`, resp.:

```
scl <- (max(dat$one) - min(dat$one)) / (max(dat$two) - min(dat$two))
ofs <- min(dat$one) - scl * min(dat$two)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = time)) +
  labs(title = "Title", x = "Time") +
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = one, col = "one")) +
  geom_line(aes(x = time, y = two * scale + ofs, col = "two")) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 6), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Left Axis",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - ofs) / scl, 
                        name = "Right Axis"),
    minor_breaks = NULL,
    breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 6)) +
  theme(legend.position = c(.90, .95),
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Now, the min and max values, resp., of both time series are plotted at the same y-values.

**Please, note** that the scale on the left side belongs to time series `one` (red line) and the scale on the right side belongs to times series `two` (blue line).

Comment: Thanks, Uwe! I think it works perfectly. Only `scale` needs to be replaced by `scl`, I think?

Comment: @Christopher, typo is fixed. Thank you for spotting.